# What software do you use to catalogue your recordings and sound fx?

Tags: recording, software, sound, design

I use Logic Pro X at the moment for basic sound design stuff. I'm trying to find some software which I can use (like several of the online download sfx libraries where you can type keywords to locate specific sounds) to catalogue any recordings I make and/or edit.

Is there anything quite like that out there? I've had a search online but am struggling to find something suitable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The market leader for this sort of thing is Soundminer, but it's quite costly. The next best thing to that is Basehead. What you're looking for really is a database management tool that uses metadata to search for sound files. At the lower end of things it's worth looking into Iced Audiofinder as well.

I'm not sure if Logic has any native metadata editing features but I know Pro Tools does. Might be worth doing some research into Logics audio file management tools.

At the bottom line you have to have everything properly organised on your drives. Know where things are in the  first place and use a sensible naming system for the files you are creating. Finder is more powerful than you might think as well. I would recommend using Finder Comments to help make it easier to find stuff. Those comments do translate over to other software as well.

In my system I organise everything with a combination of Finder, Namechanger, Pro Tools (workspace), Snapper, and Basehead. Soundminer is a necessity if you're going to sell commercial libraries so you inject metadata which will translate to the most platforms.

Have a read of Paul Virostek's articles on library management on his Creative Field Recording blog as well.